# Wordpress: SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for, Parse error: syntax error,

Tags: php, html, wordpress, content-management-system

Ok so I'm creating a theme for myself, and even when I use the most basic of loops, I still get a php error:

```
( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\wamp\www\newsite\blog\wp-content\themes\cakes\index.php on line 121
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0015  142656  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0023  144760  require( 'C:\wamp\www\newsite\blog\wp-blog-header.php' )    ..\index.php:19
3   0.3452  9323760 require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\newsite\blog\wp-includes\template-loader.php' )  ..\wp-blog-header.php:16
```

This doesn't happen with the twentyeleven theme, or any other theme I use, so I know it's not a problem with the wordpress setup. I just have no idea what it is, do I need to reference anything in my theme files?

Here's a pastebin of my index.php: http://pastebin.com/ahaFhy43 ,That's the only file besides style.css in my theme's folder.

EDIT: solved, simply had to add this to the top of my template:

```
<?php 
/* Short and sweet */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer below and mark the question as solved yourself. Otherwise it appears in the "unanswered" list. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, simply add

```
<?php 
/* Short and sweet */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

to the top of your index.php

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens when you have not cleared your site's cache. define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); in index.php will be lost once wordpress upgrade is performed